# In what colours can I build my whole model?

Tags: colour, cad

Is there a tool which, given a list of parts, will tell me the common colours, i.e. the colours that **all** the parts are available in?

Comment: Can you add more detail about the model? Do you have a set number, a plan or an image of it?

Comment: I guess you are not looking for the part-by-part solution that Bricklink provides?

Answer (score 5):

I could not find a tool with this ability, so I made one using the Rebrickable API. You can find it here:

https://gist.github.com/ali1234/836ba792390c1a5feca9a3dcb35c14af

It parses an LDraw file and selects all the bricks of a specified colour (by LDraw colour number, eg yellow = 14), then for each unique piece it requests all available colours. Finally it calculates the intersection of all colours and prints a list.

Optional rarity parameter can be used to avoid very rare parts.

Example output:

```
./colourswap pirover.ldr 14
Parts:
3665, 2730, 3660, 3455, 3005, 3002, 3702, 3703, 3700, 3701, 3895
Common Colours:
Blue, Yellow, Black, White, Light Gray, Red, Light Bluish Gray

./colourswap pirover.ldr 14 20
Parts:
3665, 2730, 3660, 3455, 3005, 3002, 3702, 3703, 3700, 3701, 3895
Common Colours:
Black, Red
```